How do I change the font of Chart.js/React-Chartjs-2 labels?
I have a Next.js personal website that I want to add features to. One of these features is a Chart using Chart.js + React-Chartjs-2. I use App Router.
The issue is that the fonts used in the chart defaults to
"'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif"

But I want to use
"'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif"

The Saira font is imported in layout.tsx where it is imported using google.
import { Saira_Extra_Condensed } from 'next/font/google'

And is implemented by inside the layout.tsx:
const Font = Saira_Extra_Condensed({
 weight: ['400', '500', '600', '700'],
 subsets: ['latin']
});
...
<body className={Font.className}>

The docs say to implement it as such:
plugins: {
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
    labels: {
      font: {
        family: "'Saira Extra Condensed', 'san-serif'"
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: stockPredictionData.attributes.company_name + ' Stock Predictions',
    font: {
      family: "'Saira Extra Condensed', 'san-serif'"
    }
  }
}

But it resorts to Times New Roman. I'm assuming it cannot find the font-family but I cannot figure out why. I found out that if I used 'Roboto' or 'Roboto Condensed' it actually finds the font and uses it.
I have tried importing the font into my css files, but still won't work.
I have tried forcing the canva element to use the font in css, but that didn't work either.
Any tips or advice is appreciated.

To customize the font in your Chart.js charts when using Next.js, you'll need to configure the chart options. Here's how you can set the font to 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif:

Add the Font to Your Project:

Ensure the font is available in your project. You can use a CDN or add the font files to your project.

For example, you can use Google Fonts by adding this line to your _app.js or _document.js:
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:wght@400;700&display=swap"
/>




Update Chart Options:

Customize the Chart.js configuration to use the desired font. You can do this when initializing your chart:
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend);

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem) {
          return tooltipItem.label + ': ' + tooltipItem.raw;
        },
      },
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'My Chart',
    },
  },
  elements: {
    bar: {
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        font: {
          family: "'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif",
        },
      },
    },
    y: {
      ticks: {
        font: {
          family: "'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  ],
};

export default function MyChart() {
  return <Bar options={options} data={data} />;
}





This configuration applies the font to both the x-axis and y-axis labels. If you want to customize other text elements, you can adjust the font property in the corresponding ticks configuration.
Feel free to adjust the font settings for other chart elements if needed!

This is a ChatGPT reply.

You can set the custom fonts to the chart using css as below:

Create a file and import the fonts as below:



@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Regular";
  src:url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Bold";
  src:url("../fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}




And import this css file in the destination page,



import "../css/robotoFonts.css";




Use the font family as below:



const poStatusPieChart = {
    labels: ["PO Received", "PO Not Received"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: poStatusData,
        backgroundColor: ["#FF6361", "#FFA600"],
      },
    ],
  };
  
const optionsForPoStatusPieChart = {
    responsive: true,
    aspectRatio: 2,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "top",
        display: true,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "PO Status",
        font: {
          family: "Roboto-Bold",
          size: 30,
          weight: "bold",
        },
      },
      subtitle: {
        display: true,
        text: "Monthly Received & Not Received PO",
        font: {
          family: "Roboto-Regular",
          size: 15,
          weight: "bold",
        },
      },
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        color: "black",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        font: {
          family: "Roboto-Regular",
          size: 15,
          weight: "bold",
        },
      },
    },
  };



The result will be as below:
enter image description here
